# How do I calculate the volume of a solid in cylindrical coordinates with triple integrals?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume

Let $G$ be the solid in the first octant enclosed by the surfaces $z = x^2 + y^2$ and $z = 36 - 3x^2 - 3y^2.$ Use cylindrical coordinates to evaluate: $$\iiint x^2+y^2\,dV.$$

I'm not entirely sure how to set up the limits of integration. I know the integration order will be $dz\,dr\,d\theta$. So far what I have is:

$$\int_{r^2}^{3(12-r^2)} \, dz$$

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Where do the two surfaces intersect?

$$x^2 + y^2 = 36 - x^2 - y^2\\
x^2 + y^2 = 9$$

$$r = 3$$

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3 (36 - 4r^2) r\ dr\ d\theta$$